# Attempted to get contract type for IService, but that type is not a ServiceContract, nor does it inherit a ServiceContract

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to create a mock for a service that doesn't have a `[ServiceContract]` attribute.

```
public class MockService : IService
{
public ServiceResult Publish(Message message)
    {
        //create a factory channel
        // NetTcpBinding myBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        try
        {
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>("ServiceEndpointConfig");
            var channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Publish(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Failed to send message", ex);
            throw;
        }
        return ServiceResult.Success;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Attempted to get contract type for IService, but that type is not a ServiceContract, nor does it inherit a ServiceContract.

What is the alternative way to use `ChannelFactory` for services that don't have `[ServiceContract]` attribute.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to reproduce a Stack Overflow?

Comment: @PaoloCosta I don't understand what you are asking? Can you clarify?

Comment: @HXD I think he means that you are mocking a service and in the call to publish you are calling publish.  Which will continue to call publish until you get an overflow.